# How to extract a number using scrapy?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

Hello and thanks for taking the time to read this. I am quite new to scrapy and am trying to scrape just one number on a website. I tried using:

```
yield {
'myitem': response.css('span.theidofmyitem').extract_first()
}
```

but this seems only to work for text as using with this number (which is contained within span) a the value of none is returned. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Try this: `response.css('span.theidofmyitem::text').extract_first()`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Unfortunately I already tried that before and it didn't work.

Comment: Have you noticed that the content you look for are not generated dynamically? If so, then you should use `selenium` or `splash` in combination with `scrapy`. However, without facing the real site it's impossible to give you any concrete solution.

Comment: I see you have `theidofmyitem` ... is that ID or a class ... if it is ID  then do `span#theidofmyitem` ...we use `#` for IDs and we use `.` for classes

Comment: Ok it all makes sense now, thank you so much Umair that was the correct answer!